# Retrieve user email via php facebook sdk API

Tags: php, facebook, api, email

I followed the example (example.php) of this project: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

It runs very well and I can retrieve a lot of informations from a facebook account (name, id, first name, last name, city...) but I cannot see the user email, that is the only thing I need...

How can I modify that page to retrieve ONLY the user email?

Thanks!

Comment: I know facebook, but fecebook? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I cannot see the user email, that is the only thing I need...

You have to ask for the `email` permission first, when the user logs in to your app – see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/

> How can I modify that page to retrieve ONLY the user email?

After getting the permission, if you don’t want all the additional fields, use the `fields` parameter in your Graph API call, as in [/me?fields=email](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me?fields%3Demail) (it’ll still give you the user id as well, but not any other info you might not need).

Answer (score -1):

You can get email by using this code

```
function fqlQuerynew() {
           FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                var query = FB.Data.query('select name,email,hometown_location, sex, pic_square from user where uid={0}', response.id);
                query.wait(function (rows) {
                    alert(rows[0].name);
                     alert(rows[0].email);
                     alert(rows[0].sex);
                     alert(rows[0].pic_square);
                });
            });
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, where can I put that function? In the file "example.php"? Anyway, thanks for your support (I'm not so expert...)
That is a Javascript call, I need it via php.
Thanks!

Comment: Or I must put it in the "with_js_sdk.php" file?